# Remark about theorem 5.8 from baby Rudin

Tags: real-analysis

> *Let $f$ be defined on $[a,b]$; if $f$ has  a local maximum at a point $x\in(a,b)$ and if $f'(x)$ exists, then $f'(x)=0$.*

I have one question. What about if $f$ has a local maximum at end-point, namely $a$ or $b$? Then this theorem is true or not?

Comment: See the $($ and $)$ in the interval defined.

Answer (score 2):

No. Consider $f(x) = x$ on any interval $[a, b]$. Actually, the theorem don't even assume that $f$ be differentiable at endpoints.

Comment: In this case $b$ is maximum of $f$. But in this case we can talk only about left-hand derivative i.e. $f'(b-)=1$. Is it normal? because $f'(b)$ is undefined.

Comment: In my example $f$ is actually differentiable at the endpoints. But the theorem in Rudin don't even require any differentiability condition at the endpoints. @RFZ

Comment: Dear John Ma! Let $f$ defined on $[a,b]$ by $x$. How $f$ can be differentiable at the endpoints? We know that $f'(b-)=f'(a+)=1$. But we can say nothing about $f'(b)$ because $f$ is not defined on the right neighborhood of $b$. Am I right?

Comment: Why your function is differentiable at the endpoints?

Comment: One can define what does it mean for a function to be differentiable at the endpoints. For example, we say that a function $f: [a, b] \to \mathbb R$ is differentiable at $b$ if there is a differentiable function $g$ defined on $(b-\epsilon, b+\epsilon)$ so that $g = f$ on $(b-\epsilon, b]$. In this sense my function is differentiable. @RFZ

Answer (score 1):

The theorem makes no claim on the maxima or minima at endpoints. It is only concerned with maxima and minima inside the interval. They may not exist.

So yes, the theorem is also true for a monotone function like $f(x)=x$.

Comment: Taking $f(x)=x$ on $[0,1]$ we see that $x=1$ is maximum of our function. But $f'(1-)=1\neq 0$. We can't talk about $f'(1)$ because we have not any information about $f$ from the right side of $1$. So theorem is false for your function.

Comment: No, as I said, the theorem makes no claim for the boundary points. Avoiding to state any claim, it remains true in that case. The proposition of the theorem is empty in that case, since there are no extrema inside the intervals, at the inner points.